# Modal pop up in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, dialog, modal-dialog

I have been searching the internet lately for an implementation of the modal dialog box for iOS programming.

I am aware of the UIAlertViewController. In fact, I am currently using this implementation in an application. But, I need something that is modal. I need the code to stop execution until the user clicks on the a button within the Alert.

So far, I haven't really seen any implementations that I am happy with. THis is the current state of my code:

```
func messageBox(messageTitle: String, messageAlert: String, messageBoxStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle, alertActionStyle: UIAlertActionStyle)
    {
        var okClicked = false
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: messageTitle, message: messageAlert, preferredStyle: messageBoxStyle)

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: alertActionStyle)
        {
            (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            okClicked = true
        }


    /*    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "Default action"), style: alertActionStyle, handler: { _ in
            okClicked = true
            NSLog("The \"OK\" alert occured.")
        }))*/

        alert.addAction(okAction)

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        while(!okClicked)
        {

        }
    }
```

Should I look into creating my own dialog box hardcore style in the storyboard or does swift have some sort of implementation that I can sorta use?

Comment: Why do you need execution to stop? Why can't you do what is needed in the handler for the OK button?

Comment: Using while() doesn't sound good.  Use the completion block if necessary.

Comment: You should never under any circumstances do something like this.  While you app may do nothing while the alert is displayed it should still have the capability to respond.  What is your reason for trying to do something like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want your own helper function but want to execute code only after the okay button has been clicked, you should look at adding a completion handler to the helper function. Here's an example:

```
func messageBox(messageTitle: String, messageAlert: String, messageBoxStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle, alertActionStyle: UIAlertActionStyle, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: messageTitle, message: messageAlert, preferredStyle: messageBoxStyle)

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: alertActionStyle) { _ in
            completionHandler() // This will only get called after okay is tapped in the alert
        }

        alert.addAction(okAction)

        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

I've removed unneeded code from your function and added a completion handler as the last argument. This completion handler is basically a function, and you can call it whenever you want, in this case we're calling it when the okay button is tapped. Here's how you use the function:

```
viewController.messageBox(messageTitle: "Hello", messageAlert: "World", messageBoxStyle: .alert) {
    print("This is printed into the console when the okay button is tapped")
}
```

`() -> Void` means "a function that takes no parameters, that returns no value", and `@escaping` means that the function will be called at a later date asynchronously, in this case we're calling it from the alert action's handler for when the button is tapped.

Answer (score 0):

```
// declare an alert 
let alert = UIAlertController(title: <#Your Title#>, message:  <#Your Message#> preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)
//create action and add them to alert
let actionX = UIAlertAction(title:  <#Your Title#>, style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: {(action) in
     // do whatever you want  
}))
alert.addAction(actionX)
```

You should look at closures to understand how you can code easily in swift

Comment: The dollar signs are a little confusing because they are used for different things in Swift. Might be nice to either just use placeholder strings or actual Xcode placeholders like: `<#Your Title#>`, so when it's copied into Xcode it turns into a placeholder :)